# shopify how to get product data using php in my localhost

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

I am looking a php script to get shopify product data by using php in my localhost server.I have already created storefront api but don't have idea about it that how we will call using api key and fetch data.

I read a lot of document which are related to same but nothing explore for php.
https://help.shopify.com/api/storefront-api/getting-started#using-curl
If anybody know about it please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can make simple curl request for getting products detail using shopify 
admin api

Request Pattern

```
https://{api_key}:{shared_secrete}@shop_url.myshopify.com/admin/products.json
```

Here i am using ,  [Guzzle](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/) ( PHP HTTP client )  to create curl reuqest.

But , you can also  make curl request to make api call

giving you one example

```
 $requestUrl = 'https://'.$username.':'$password.'@'.$shop_domain. '/admin/products.json';

 $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();

 $response = $client->request('GET', $requestUrl, [
    'headers' => [
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
        'Accept' => 'application/json'
     ]
 ]);

 $products = json_decode($response->getBody());
```

So, Here you will get the products detail in json format

But , remember this is for private app only for the public app you need a access-token from shopify API while sent in the call back after app install on the shop. save it on your local database. attach this token in each request to API and get data

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to get the Products with PHP you can simply use their Rest API.

Once you create a private app you get a similar URL: 
`https://APIKEY:PASSWORD@STORENAME.myshopify.com/admin/products.json`

Where you will need to replace your APIKEY, PASSWORD and STORENAME with your own.

And from there on if you know PHP it will be very easy to pull the JSON response from this URL.

That's all.

Comment: This is asking password but after putting correct credential ,its asking credential again and again,what could be reason?I have private app in my shopify store.

Comment: while able to find result when open url in same window where I have logged in my store admin.

Comment: @akgola When you create the APP you have an Example URL below the password and above the shared secret, use that and try to open it. ( it will have `orders.json` at the end, just changed it to `products.json` ) Since it seems that you are copy/pasting the wrong credentials.

Comment: This will redirect to login page when store user is not loggedIn. Need help.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution to get the list of products from a public APP using Guzzle:

```
$url = "https://{$shopId}.myshopify.com/admin/api/2021-04/products.json";
$client = new GuzzleHttp/Client();
$headers = [
  'X-Shopify-Access-Token' => $oauthToken,
  'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
];
$response = $client->get($url, ['verify' => false, 'headers' => $headers]);
return (string) $response->getBody();
```