# Attempting to access Shopify api from localhost with a GET request

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

Currently I'm trying to access data from my shopify store through local host and I'm getting the CORS error.  I realize this question has been asked but I couldn't find an answer.  Also I realize that this is a bad practice since credentials are exposed.  I have a local computer that for a reason (with out taking the time to explain it) needs to be able to GET data from my shopify store.  This HAS to be done in javascript so I am using XMLHttpRequest like so:

```
var url = "https://apikey:secretkey@mystore.myshopify.com/admin/orders.json?limit=25&page=2";
```

this is based on this answer on SO: [shopify how to get product data using php in my localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47792055/shopify-how-to-get-product-data-using-php-in-my-localhost)

In the above I'm passing my apikey and secret key from an app I've setup and approved on my account.  One thing I didn't do is whitelist my ip which I'm not sure if that's what would allow me to get the data.  This returns a CORS error.

I've also tried this:

```
var url = "https://username:password@mystore.myshopify.com/admin/orders.json?limit=25&page=2";
```

Here I pass my username and password and I get the CORS error also.

What is a challenge is that if I'm logged into the account or not logged in when I go to my browser window I can go to this url: `"https://username:password@mystore.myshopify.com/admin/orders.json?limit=25&page=2";` and the json data appears in my browser window.

Again this has to be done in javascript and it has to be done from a local computer.

Comment: Does your local environment run an SSL certificate? If not, just set one and there shouldn't be any issues.

Comment: No but I'll give it a try tomorrow @drip

Comment: @drip got the same error.  I also tried from a remote server with ssl.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I went about this is forget the XMLHttpRequest.  To access the shopify api via my local host I used the node library provided here:  https://www.npmjs.com/package/shopify-api-node

I'm marking this as the answer just in case someone in the future is attempting to do this.