# How to get my shopify app files included in the theme?

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-template

I hope you are doing well.

I am creating a Public App in Shopify. 
The app is for Product Listing, built in Ruby on Rails. It working fine in the admin panel.
I am able to show products & their details.
Now my aim is to connect the app with the frontend (website).
I have used app proxy for connecting it with frontend but, for that, we need to specify a URL, in my case /apps/{{sub-prefix}}

Now I wanted to know how we can include my assets in a theme whenever the user is installing it from the URL.
Like we Install "Product Filter & Searchby BoostCommerce",
then in theme, files are automatically added in Snippets, Assets, etc.
Please guide me on how to connect it.

Some example or code sample would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make API calls.

First Get active theme ID. for that make GET API call.

```
GET /admin/api/2019-10/themes.json
```

In the response you will get all themes you loop through this data and find theme id having role **main**

Now you can make PUT request to insert your snippet/template in the Live Theme

```
PUT /admin/api/2019-10/themes/#{theme_id}/assets.json
{
  "asset": {
    "key": "templates/index.liquid",
    "value": "<img src='backsoon-postit.png'><p>We are busy updating the store for you and will be back within the hour.</p>"
  }
}
```

Change key to

> snippets/index.liquid

if you want to add your file in the snippets as shown below

Shopify Document Link : 
https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/online-store/asset#update-2019-10

Comment: Thanks for the reply @bhargav_kaklotara, I understood the process you provided but, don't know how and where to make these API calls foe assets. As I mentioned I already made the App-proxies for which I have to hit the path every time.  I tried the method you suggested and implemented this in my one of the controller files. Still didn't get anything. Can you tell me where to put this code and how I can make successful API call. And also what is "Key: snippets/index.liquid" in your response(do I have to include this in my route file).

Comment: Key Defines file name and location. if you split key by / then first one is the group of files where we want to add our new file ( .i.e. snippets,templates etc.) and second one is the name of file. and  parameters => key,value will be sent with request body while making API calls. no need to add in route files.

for making a successful Shopify API call you need to use any request making client like CURL, GUZZLE .

if you are confuse how to do this follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47792055/shopify-how-to-get-product-data-using-php-in-my-localhost/47880476#47880476

Comment: App, Proxy is used when you want to make a call ( mostly ajax call ) from your Shopify Store to your back-end App. it is the secure way of communication from Shopify to your App.

Comment: Hello Kaklotara,
I hope you are doing well.Thanks for the reply I understood the meaning of "KEY".
But still, don't know how to include this in my files and where to call API call(on which file or something).

Comment: Have you read this thread ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47792055/shopify-how-to-get-product-data-using-php-in-my-localhost/47880476#47880476

if yes have you any question about it ?

Have you made successful calls to Shopify for any endpoint ?

Comment: API calls are made on Shopify to different end-Points to achieve different results. .i.e 
you want to do something with products then your endpoint will be /admin/api/2019-10/products.json. now you can make request on this end point with necessary headers and request body ( request body is mostly send while making put request to edit product object and post to create new product ).  in your case you are editing themes so your end point will be /admin/api/2019-10/themes.json and you want to add files you in existing theme so you should make PUT request with request body.....

Comment: And in the request body you need to pass whole file data (value) and key as request body. key will define where the file will be included with which name and value will hold whole file content. Hope this will help.

Comment: Hello @Bhargav_Kaklotara, hope you are doing well. Now, I totally understood your procedure that I have to call "Theme API" for getting the current active theme by their role. And after that calling "Assets API" for retrieving the "Key" value. But, now my concern is where to put the following API's code, is it in my "application_controller.rb or home_controller.rb(main controller)". All the methods present in home_controller.rb file are displaying in the admin panel correctly. Now, do I have to make another controller for the frontend content or it automatically includes that snippet.

Comment: Making new controller or not is up to you no matter you create or not. if your app need this files need to be installed instantly after app installation then you can put this code  in the controller which is being called right after merchant install the app. And for including new files in the theme assets you no need to retrieve this you just need to make POST API call with key and value. key define type and name of the file and value should have the file content in string format.

Comment: I am calling API for get asset but getting blank response. Please check code schreenshot: http://prntscr.com/sfx44s and  response screenshot: http://prntscr.com/sfx3lj @BhargavKaklotara

Comment: getting id of theme  on your first call ?

Answer (score 0):

Fast forward to 2024, Shopify applications can be embedded in the storefront.

1. One can build theme app extensions
2. One can make use of App proxy to get data from external HTTP APIs
3. One can also make use of Script tags (though this is getting deprecated)

The [Shopify documentation](https://shopify.dev/docs/apps/online-store) is quite detailed in itself.