# Is there any way to get a profile of owner of shopify account or app or store?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, shopify, shopify-javascript-buy-sdk, shopify-api-node

https://help.shopify.com/en/api/getting-started/authentication/oauth

I am using Shopify login for my app and it almost works but I am stuck getting a customer profile from the access token.

https://{shop}.myshopify.com/admin/oauth/access_token

I use this API and now I have access token so how can I get data from that token?

Answer (score 2):

There are two types of API you can access in Shopify.

1. Admin API
2. Store Front API.

**Admin API**

For Admin API you can create Public App / Private App.

If you are using Public app then you need to perform oAuth and get AccessToken. And in the each API call you need to pass this accessToken in header as I have suggested in the First Answer.

If you are using Private App you just need to add APIKey and Secret in the request URL. follow below post for detail.

[shopify how to get product data using php in my localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47792055/shopify-how-to-get-product-data-using-php-in-my-localhost/47880476#47880476)

**StoreFront API**

For the store Front API you also can use both public and private APP.

Let me explain private app first.

for the private app you need to check **Allow this app to access your storefront data using the Storefront API** and give appropriate permission to the app. once you set permission and save app. you will get **Storefront access token** now you can pass this token in each request header to access your store data using storeFront API. and **StoreFront API just accessible with graphQL only**. see below example how to query storeFront API.

https://help.shopify.com/en/api/storefront-api/getting-started#storefront-api-authentication

Now, **Public App with StoreFront API**

First you need to perform oAuth and get Store AccessToken. now with passing this accessToken in header and make below request to get your **storefront access token**.

```
POST /admin/api/2019-10/storefront_access_tokens.json
{
  "storefront_access_token": {
    "title": "Test"
  }
}
```

For more detailed version visit [here](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/access/storefrontaccesstoken#create-2019-10)

In the response you will get **storefront access token**, now you can add this accessToken in your **shopify-javascript-buy-sdk** and can make your storeFront API calls.

[Js BuySdk Documentation](https://shopify.github.io/js-buy-sdk/#installation)

But remember one thing, Storefront API access tokens are not secret. You can place them in a JavaScript file or any public HTML document.And you need to make your public app as [sales channel](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/guides/sales-channel-sdk/getting-started#creating-a-sales-channel-app) in order to use Store Front API

Hope this will make sense and will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make an API call in below end point in order to get stores basic detail like email domain,currency etc.

```
GET /admin/api/2019-10/shop.json
```

while making a shopiy API call you have to pass accessToken in the request header.
i.e.

```
'headers'  => [
    'Accept'=>'application/json',
    'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
    'X-Shopify-Access-Token'=>$accessToken // access token
],
```

Comment: I am encountering this type of error.
{
    "errors": "[API] Invalid API key or access token (unrecognized login or wrong password)"
}
Please look into this that what are my mistake and correct me.

Comment: I  am using this api https://test-mobcoder.myshopify.com/admin/api/2019-10/shop.json

Comment: you might have missed these configurations. 1 ) add API key and API secret key  the SDK you are using  2 ) you might not including shopify accessToken in API call request header.  have you done both the things ?

Comment: if you are using JavaScript Buy SDK then have you followed below instructions ?
 https://help.shopify.com/en/api/storefront-api/tools/js-buy-sdk/getting-started#generate-an-access-token-for-the-javascript-buy-sdk

Comment: yes,I have done both the things and I am using this process  https://help.shopify.com/en/api/getting-started/authentication/oauth

Comment: Are you using oAuth process or the javaScript buy SDK ?

Comment: I am using OAuth process.

Comment: What is your primary goal ? you want to use Admin API or Storefront API or both of them ?

Comment: which package/SDK you are using or you are writing custom code ? in this scenario you do not need to use store front API you just need to use Admin api / with public app. you just need perform oAuth and make API call as suggested in first answer.

Comment: I am writing custom code and I use only Oauth/admin api but I am stuck into profile section.Please help me in this.

Comment: if you are passing AccessToken in the header and making request to correct endpoint this should not happened. Please paste your tried code in the questions so people can point where you have made a  small mistake.